# Postgres @> Any Value

Tags: sql, node.js, json, postgresql, where-clause

I have a query that is checking the jsonb `genre` column and returning all movies that contain a passed genre number. As so:

```
SELECT id, name, year, description, "avgRating", "posterPath", genres, "trailerPath", seen 
FROM movies 
WHERE genres @> $1 
ORDER BY year desc
```

So if I pass '18' as `$1` (the `$1` is coming from a node module) an example row would be:

[image: example row]

On the front end drop down have also included an 'ALL' choice that can be passed. Originally i just had my server detect the 'ALL' value and instead run a query for the entire table. The current implementation is unfortunately causing issues with combining filters for queries now, So my question is whether there is a value I can pass to the `@>` operator that would return movies with any genre or do I need to change the structure of my query?

--- edit pertaining to passing arrays to the query ---

Testing solution queries in pgAdmin 4 i pass the following:

`SELECT id, name, year, description, "avgRating", "posterPath", genres, "trailerPath", seen  FROM movies  WHERE genres @> [18]  ORDER BY year desc`

And I get back the following error:

`ERROR:  syntax error at or near "[" LINE 3: WHERE genres @> [18]  ^ SQL state: 42601 Character: 122`

The arrow is intended to point at the opening array bracket point out the location of the error

Comment: Something like `WHERE genres @> coalesce(nullif($1, 'ALL'), genres)` should do it

Comment: @MikeOrganek That doesn't work for me. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=9fdba1f56a25abd2c2b83a4e60d57bf8 Even when properly casting text to jsonb, it still fails.

Comment: i had the same issue as @MartinBurch

Comment: @iwantmyhatback  Please see Martin Burch's answer, below.  It is more correct than what I suggested.

Comment: @MartinBurch  It works with the cast in this fiddle:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=0c31fc26cc20230f54df0127f1fde2c2

Comment: Ah, that's great @MikeOrganek ! I think the cast I tried was in the wrong spot. Nice solution. Please post an answer :)

Comment: @iwantmyhatback the syntax error is caused by not putting single quote marks around the json string. instead of `genres @> [18]` it should be `genres @> '[18]'` The quotes are for postgres, not part of the json.

Comment: @MartinBurch ahh got it, you are correct!

Comment: @MartinBurch  I won't post an answer because yours is better :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@>` operator is the [contains operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html). You should pass an array `[18]` instead of a string `18`. Then you could pass an empty array `[]` if no particular filter was set.

```
WHERE genres @> []
```

[db<>fiddle example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=bfc62d914a32f532dc777846cfffc068)

Comment: This is the behavior i had expected, however whenever i try to pass `[18]` i get a syntax error

Comment: @iwantmyhatback how about `WHERE genres @> '$1'`? make sure the `$1` substitution is being JSON.stringify()'d and that it contains an array of numbers, not an array of strings, to match the database. For example `["18"]` won't work (at least in my example, anyway). If this persists, please edit the question to add your syntax error. There should be a hint if it's from postgres. What is your postgres version?

Comment: psql (PostgreSQL) 12.4 -- i will have to try with stringify when I am home, right now i am just testing solutions by querying the DB directly in pgAdmin4.

Comment: This certainly shouldn't be a problem in pgAdmin. My example works in Postgres 12 too. Perhaps posting your table CREATE and some rows from your INSERT would help us understand.

Answer (score 0):

You could use boolean logic like so:

```
WHERE $1 = 'ALL' OR genres ? $1
```

Note that this uses `?` instead of `@>`: the latter searches for a *jsonb* value in the jsonb array, while the former searches for a *text* value - which seems to be what you want.

Comment: be careful and wrap this `OR` statement in parens if you add any other conditions to your where clause: `WHERE ($1 = 'ALL' OR genres ? $1) AND year > $2` etc.